# Custom DataTable/DataRow to XML serialization

Tags: c#, xml, datatable

There are things that I dont like in DataTable.WriteXML() and .ReadXML(). These are:

- Not possible to configure number of rows or columns to load/save.
  Need it when processing huge data amounts
- Not even possible to get
  rid of the XML element that means dataset name (DocumentElement by
  default)
- Want to make custom processing on read/write nodes

Is there any good serializer for DataRows and DataTables? I can write my own but it seems weird that they still don;t exist (i tried to find).
Thanks!

Comment: An XML File can have only one root element so the DataSet name is the root.  You can change the name of the data set using new DataSet("Name").  You can easily copy a dataset/datatabe by filtering on the rows you and then saving the copy.

Comment: @jdweng i don't have and don't want to use datasets while saving datatables to file. I'd like to simply specify that tag.

Comment: You can use DataTable WriteXML() method but you have to specify a name for the datatable like : new DataTable("MyTable").  If yo udon't specify the name then you get an exception.